# EclipseLink & Spring Config without Persistence.xml

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink

I am having trouble figuring out how to configure EclipseLink with Spring without using a Persistence.xml file. I want to configure static weaving with EclipseLink too to avoid all those pesky LazyLoadExceptions from Hibernate.

The following was my Hibernate & Spring configuration that worked fine. I want to do something similar with EclipseLink but really struggling to find complete and relevant docs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.something.ots.repository" />

    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="${datasource.jndi.name}" id="dataSource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.dscreative.honda.ots</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">${hibernate.connection.charSet}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="${jpa.vendor.database}" />
        <property name="showSql" value="${jpa.vendor.showSql}"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="${jpa.vendor.generateDdl}"/>
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="${jpa.vendor.databasePlatform}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using spring data with EclipseLink with PostgreSql dbms.My configuration is annotation based. It is easy to transform it to xml configuration. The above is my persistent configuration,

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.PersistenceUnitProperties;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
    "package.with.repositories1",
    "package.with.repositories2"
})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceContext {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbName");
        dataSource.setUsername("usernameForDd");
        dataSource.setPassword("passwordForDd");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.PostgreSQLPlatform");
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.FALSE);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(EnvironmentVariables.getInstance().getBoolean("app.showSql", Boolean.FALSE));

        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaDialect(new EclipseLinkJpaDialect());

        // Instead of persistence.xml
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("yourPersistenceUnitName");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(
                "package.with.entities1",
                "package.with.entities2"
        );

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.WEAVING, "static");
        jpaProperties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.CACHE_SHARED_DEFAULT, "false");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        entityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setLoadTimeWeaver(new ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why, but `entityManagerFactoryBean.setLoadTimeWeaver(new ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver())` was giving me an error. Commenting it out allowed my application to boot.

Comment: Any reason why `SessionLog.ALL` throws a `ClassCastException`? In any case, even with `FINEST_LABEL`, I somehow don't see any SQL being logged. I also have `jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true)`.